# Can anyone help me identify this Coat of Arms?

Tags: europe, identification, monarchy, heraldry, silver

Can anyone help me identify this coat of arms?
As far as I can identify, there are 2 Lion Rampant regardant.
A Pelican in her nest, a crown, a shield with stars.
It is on a small galleried tray that I purchased in France.
There are no markings on the back.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a Star of David in the center with 2 joined Stars of David encompassing it. Maybe a Jewish family?

Comment: Horizontal hatching is usually azure/blue

Answer (score 2):

My answer uses heraldic terminology in the English language.

Technically only the shield and the design on it is a coat of arms.

The other things with the shield are various heraldic accessories.   The shield andy any herladic accessories with it make up an achievement of arms or a heraldic achievement.

The ribbon like shape below the shield is a scroll, and a motto would usually be put on a scroll.

The two lions on teh sides of the sield are called supportrs because they hold onto the shield and support it.

The pelican in its nest is usally called "a pelican in her piety", wounding herself so that her hatchlings can feed on the blood. Being on top of the coronet or helmet makes the pelican a crest.

Identifying the type of coronet used could identify the rank claimed for the user of the coat of arms.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_(heraldry)[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_(heraldry)%5B1%5D)

If the coat of arms can be described in heraldic language, or blazoned, someone could search for a coat of arms matching that blazon.

As Henry said, the horizontal lines in the shield are an example of hatching, using lines to indicate the colors in a coat of arms when it is depicted in black and white. Horizontal lines indicate the heraldic color azure (blue) in the main system of heraldic hatching, but have been used to represent gules (red) in some other less used systems.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatching_(heraldry)[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatching_(heraldry)%5B2%5D)

In the English language the color of the field of the coat of arms is mentioned first, and the charge onthe coat of arms is mentioned second.

So the blazon would be "Azure, a ________".

According to the rule of tincture inh eraldry, a charge should be one of the "metals" - Or (gold/yellow) or Argent (silver/white) - if it is placed on a field of one of the heraldic colors - red, green, blue, purple, or black.

Since the field is very probably blue, the charge should be either white or yellow.

So the coat of arms would be blazoned in Eanglish as "Azure, a ______ Argent" or "Azure, a ______ Or."

And if you can add a better picture of the charge on the coat of arms, maybe someone can didentify it and make a full blazon of the coat of arms in English or some other language and search online for it.

Comment: I'm going to toss in a couple of my observations. First, a source for translation [Illustrated atlas of French and English heraldic terms](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Illustrated_atlas_of_French_and_English_heraldic_terms). Second, the shield seems to have a border in [Or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tincture_(heraldry)). Comments mention Star of David, but virtually all French stars(mullets) are displayed as six sided. On the same line of thought, the pelican in her piety is often given strong *Christian* [connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelican#Christianity).

Comment: Another item of interest is that the  coronet is displayed with three mullets, pierced. This might be fairly unique, and a point to research.